# How to fill an array with empty items in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Project is using Angular/Typescript

I have an array that is automatically populated by 4 invisible items
which still take screen space (intended) : 
(TS)

```
 public invisibles= []
this.invisibles = Array(4).fill(0)
```

(HTML)

```
<div style="display:flex">
 <p style="visibility=hidden" *ngFor="let invisible of invisibles">Zero</p>
  </div>
```

This creates **"**                                                           **"**

Now i want to be able to add another object into this array, that is **visible** and can be **sorted** into the middle of the array like eg. `this.comments.splice(3, 0, visible)`;

The end result should then look like

**"                 visible                "**

The problem is that ngfor doesnt accept two variables. So maybe there is a way to fill the empty items another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngClass` like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
public invisibles: number[] = [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ];
```

**app.compoent.css**

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <p [ngClass]="{'invisible': item == 0}" *ngFor="let item of invisibles">{{ item }}</p>
</div>
```

But this is not a good way if you just want to add some indentation and it's better ti use `CSS` features. But if you just want to process an array and add something in an arbitrary index you can process it using `map()` as follows:

```js
this.invisibles = Array(5).fill(0);
invisibles.map(( _ , index ) =>  { if (index == 2) { return 1  } else { return _ }});
```